# How to handle layout screens for all android device sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got an enhancement of one application. It is developed for 10.1 inch  tablet.  However it is working nice for tabs with size 10.1’ and for other screen sizes UI is poorly aligned. I need to do the changes in application so that it will be as good as 10.1 inch app for all other screen sizes(>4 inches).

I have few doubts here on my approaches.

1)  I have found “size qualifiers” in android developer’s site.  How many type of layouts need to use for each screen to make good for all sizes in android world.

Note: All screens in this application are always on land scape orientation. Is size qualifiers still works here?

2)  Somewhere I found in “stack overflow “, It is already developed for 10.1 inches so that use percentages and change to every screen size.

```
100%  -> 10.1’
?     ->  7’
```

Which one is good and proper solution for maintenance also? Is there any other best solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard and fast answer.
It is up to you to determine how many screen sizes you want to optimize for.

I'd suggest optimising for small, mid and large with layout qualifiers:
1) size qualifiers do work in landscape as they assess based on smallest screen width.

```
layout
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw800dp
```

2) I dont understand your question... i've never seen percentages used in Android layouts

Answer (score 0):

There are so many different screen sizes that you can adapt your layout to..

In Eclipse's graphical layout you can also choose the screen size and resolution for which you want to develop (you can define the screen sizes and resolution and you will see how the layout looks on each of them).

You can also have several images that will be chosen automatically for each screen size via the `drawable` folder. You got `drawable-hdpi` for high density screens, `drawable-xhdpi` for extra high density screens and so on.. you can change an image to adapt to many of the screen size using Google's `Android Asset Studio` :   http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

You should also read the Android developers guide:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html